# Firebase security rules how to overcome cascading

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am writing a polling app with Firebase backend. Users answer to yes/no questions. I want only those who answered a question to be able to see the results and, only a user's friends to be able to see that the user has answered a question. How should I structure it and write the security rules? Below is my attempt

```
questions:
    question1:
        readable:
            text: "Did you have a good day?"
            yes_count: 37
            no_count: 24
        answers:
            user1: yes
            user2: no
            ...
            user100: yes

users:
    user1:
        friends:
            user3
            user4
```

I came up with the following security rule. It hides answers but not identities. With cascading, I don't know how to limit access to only those who have answered the question

```
questions:
    $qid:
        answers:
           $uid:
               ".read": root.child("users").child(auth.uid).child("friends").child(uid).exists()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current `read` rule for the `questions/$qid/answers` path can be used to determine whether any particular user's friends have answered a question, but an additional rule is necessary to answer the first part (`I want only those who answered a question to be able to see the results`). In order to do that you need a rule for the `yes_count` and `no_count` paths, like so:

```
questions:
    $qid:
        answers:
            $uid:
                ".read": root.child("users").child(auth.uid).child("friends").child(uid).exists()
        readable:
            text:
                ".read": true
                ".write": false
            $child:
                ".read": "data.parent().parent().child('answers').child(auth.uid).exists()"
                ".write": false
```

Notice the double use of `.parent()` inside the `questions/$qid/readable/$child` read rule. That is so it can go up two paths (to `$qid`), then down to `answers` child to determine whether the logged in user's id exists there. `$child` here will only be `yes_count` or `no_count`, unless you change your data structure at some further point in the future.